# Why can't I compare these hex values?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, hex

I've got two sets of hex values as such:

```
---------- ------------------
0x0062EB3F 0x000000020062EB3F
0x0062EF17 0x000000020062EF17
0x0062EF30 0x000000020062EF30
0x0062EF38 0x000000020062EF38
0x0062EF3B 0x000000020062EF3B
0x0062EF3F 0x000000020062EF3F
0x0062EF40 0x000000020062EF40
```

The only difference is the leading zeros, these are all the same number as the one next to it.  So why won't MSSQL count them as being equal? Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you comparing them?  What type are these columns?

Comment: Just spotted the extra 2 in there - that'll probably answer my question, sorry guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, they're different for more than just the leading zeros:

```
 0x        0062EB3F 
 0x000000020062EB3F
          *
          *
```

There's an extra "2" in there..... so they are **not** the same!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the numbers you listed in your question are not the same:

```
0x0062EB3F  !=  0x000000020062EB3F
                         ^
```

Notice, the number on the right has an extra 2

Also, it depends on what type of data SQL server is using to store the numbers. If they are stored as INT or BIGINT, then  0x0001 is equivalent to 0x1, but if they are stored as VARBINARY for instance - then 0x0001 is not the same as 0x1.